# update session variables inside Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, session-variables

I have a page called index.php where i have all my php functions, javascripts and html tags.
Upon button click (add to cart) event i want to call a php function ( addtToCart($itemID) ) to update session variables. Can you tell me how to implement this in my code ?

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['Mid']=""; 
$_SESSION['$UserName']="test"; ?>

//html part
<button id='cart' 
onclick="<script>idk how to call my function here</script>"
class="w3-button">ADD TO CART</button>

 //my php function
<?php
  function addToCart($Mid){
    if(!isset($_SESSION['$UserName'])){
            header('Location:signin.html');
    }
    $_SESSION['Mid'].="+".$Mid;
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert(\"ADDED TO CART\");</script>";
  }
?>
```

Comment: Use aJax, javascript can't directly affect session variable.

Comment: you can use this `var javaScriptVariable = <?php echo $_SESSION['$UserName'];?>` in your javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Use an aJax call to call another PHP script that updates it:

```
        var SendInfo= {     "your": data,
                            "your1": data1 };


        $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'https://yourscript.com/updatesession.php',
                data: SendInfo,
                contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
                traditional: true,
                success: function (data) {
                    //dostuff
                }
        });
```